# Classic ASP: URL issues when duplicating an application

Tags: url, asp-classic, relative-path

I have an old Classic ASP application that I want to duplicate in parallel - that is, I want to configure another copy (talking to a different database) alongside the original.

So where I have //MyServer/MyApp1/, I will also soon have //MyServer/MyApp2/... so far so good.

Except that many URLs in the app are absolute (for example JS and CSS files), e.g. `<script type="text/javascript" src="/MyApp1/menu.js"></script>`.

I could search for references to `/MyApp1/` and replace it with `/MyApp2/`, but it's an annoying task that I will have to repeat as I update the core application, and in the event of wanting other copies creating - a likelihood albeit temporary.

I could change these URLs to parent paths, but this means I need to refer to each resource differently, depending on where in the application folder structure I am. Again, it would work, but I don't like using parent paths for a number of reasons.

Given that there is no tilde (~) feature in Classic ASP (to refer to the application root), are there any alternatives that I can consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CJM: I usually have a `db.asp` which contains the `function`s and `sub`s that handle opening/closing database connections as the primary include on practically all of my pages. In this `db.asp` I would then define a `appurl` or `absurl` path which could, in your case, have `/MyApp1`, and then you can use `<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=appurl %>/menu.js"></script>` in your scripts.

The first time you do it, it'll be a bit of a search/replace mission, but once it's done, subsequent "duplicate" projects will just need that one variable updated.

Comment: Actually, I did consider that alternative. I'm not sure if I'll need to repeat the operation often enough to justify the effort, but the OCD part of me thinks its a matter of principle! This solution might be as good as any other.

Answer (score 0):

In Classic ASP, You can use `Server.MapPath("/")` to get the root directory, or `Server.MapPath(".")` to get the current directory.

Comment: Server.MapPath returns a physical path an not a URL - it's the URL that I am interested in.